# Transform Tensor to a vector

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, neural-network, keras

I have a tensor with shape:

**2 x 2 x 3 x 2**

namely: {player, round, number of raises, action taken}

It's a two player game, which ends after two rounds while maximum 3 raises can be done and each raise contains the information about the taken action.

I want to create an array which represents every step of the game. So i have the information about every players action for each raise, for each round.

Is there any possibility to do something like this:

```
players = array[0, 1]
rounds = array[2, 3]
raises = array[4, 5, 6]
actions = array[7, 8]

niceAndHandyArray = someFunction(players, rounds, raises, actions)
# Which outputs something like this:
[
    [0, [
            2, [
                   4, [7, 8]
                ],
            ...
        ],
    [1, 
         ... 
    ]
]

# And then access it like:
niceAndHandyAcrray[player_index][round_index][raise_index][action_index] = 1

# And pass it to my neural network later on as:
niceAndHandyArray.flatten()
```

Comment: What do your `players`, `rounds`, etc. arrays contain here? Shouldn't e.g. `len(actions) == 24` (`2 x 2 x 3 x 2`)?

Comment: It would be nice if you used meaningful values so we can know which is which in your resulting array. But it seems you're trying to create elements with different shapes inside it, which is not feasible in a single tensor in keras.

Comment: Sorry you're right. A vector length of 24 (i have to concatenate some additional information later on, which adds an array of length 6 to it). I try to create a "betting history" out of the given arrays (players, rounds, raises, actions). I'll edit my question quickly.

Comment: How is your data organized? Do you really have such arrays? How do you know then which action goes to which player?

Comment: The code above is just for the game environment. If player1 does something e.g. `env.step(player1_action)` then i want to update the "betting history" like `niceAndHandyArray[player1_index][round][raise_index][player1_action] =  1` and then return the new betting history `return niceAndHandyArray.flatten()` which represents a part of the game state. I just try to manage the whole history as easy as possible.

Comment: What I (we?) are trying to say is that your input data as shown in your snippet (`players`, `rounds`, etc.) look incomplete. You would need 24 values to define your tensor, while you are providing only 9 (`0...8`). If `[7, 8]` are the values of the 2 actions taken by player `0` for round `2`, raise `4`; what about the actions for the other players / raises / rounds?

Comment: Of course you need to append the actions to every `player/round/raise` so in the end there are 24 data tuples which specify the the exact action for the a specific raise on a specific round from a specific player. `actions = array[7, 8]` was just to show that there are two actions to take. Not the total amount of actions taken in the game. It's just the actions space. I guess i'm not super skilled in writing questions. Actually if have solved it right now with multiple loops: `for player in players: for round in rounds: ... raise.append(actions) // rounds.append(raise) ...`

Comment: Anyways, i just tried to create some placeholder. In the beginning nearly every entry in the `niceAndHandyArray` is **zero**. Then for every step taken by the agents, the `niceAndHandyArray` has to be updated.

Comment: Maybe just `np.zeros((2,2,3,2))`?

Comment: **solved** that's what i was looking for!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try use [reshape](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/reshape):

```
#Example:
# tensor 't' is [[[1, 1, 1],
#                 [2, 2, 2]],
#                [[3, 3, 3],
#                 [4, 4, 4]],
#                [[5, 5, 5],
#                 [6, 6, 6]]]
# tensor 't' has shape [3, 2, 3]
# pass '[-1]' to flatten 't'
tf.reshape(t, [-1])
#output: [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6]
```

Comment: My question is not how to flatten tensor 't' when it is already set up. My question is how to produce tensor 't' out of the given array's (players, rounds, raises, actions). But thanks for your reply!